# Codeigniter Post data using AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, http-post, forms

I've built CRUD application using Codeigniter + AngularJS

how to post data in code-igniter controller

I am using this function get all POST data

```
$data = json_decode($this->input->raw_input_stream , TRUE);
```

But I want specific value using this function but response is NULL

```
$x = $this->input->input_stream('email', TRUE);
```

and one more question is how to apply code-igniter form validation 
for this $data

Thank You
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try following way.

I've assumed your code and provided an example, do the necessary changes as per your need.

**Angular Js**

```
console.log("posting data....");
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/add',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data: JSON.stringify({name: $scope.name,city:$scope.city})
}).success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.message = data.status;
});
```

**Controller action**

```
public function add()
{
   // Here you will get data from angular ajax request in json format so you have to decode that json data you will get object array in $request variable
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $name = $request->name;
    $city = $request->city;
    $id = $this->user_model->AddUser($name,$city);
    if($id)
    {
     echo $result = '{"status" : "success"}';
    }else{
     echo $result = '{"status" : "failure"}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank For your reply but how to use codeigniter form validation in your function add because server side form validation not applying i'm trying more time please tell me

Comment: You can do it on server side and send the validation success  / failure message accordingly
Ex.
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$this->form_validation->set_rules($data->name, 'Name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
if(!$this->form_validation->run()) { 
echo $result = '{"errors" : validation_errors()}'; 
}

Comment: @Nepster See how codeigniter do the validation
But you need to get the post data and then you need to check validation and then return the result to client (angular) and show that message.

Comment: Thank You for reply but validation not applying  error occur The first_name field is required

Comment: What problem your getting?

Comment: Deprecation Notice (v1.5)
The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error.